# Can i make the XCode UITableViewCellEditingStyle NOT offset?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, cell

I am making a new app in Xcode 4.3.1 and i am using a UITableView in which i have a custom appearance. Basically i have 1 image that takes up almost the entire 320 pixels across. So when i implement the editing (rearranging of the cells), apple does the default push everything to the right by 50 pixels or so thing. I want there to be NO movement what so ever. just show the little lines at the right so you can drag the cells. I am not allowing deleting or inserting so i have my style always set to UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone, but when in editing mode, this leaves a space where a little icon would be at the left BUT again, i want there to be NO space at the left and just the lines at the right for dragging. Any ideas?

here is some sample code:

```
// The editing style for a row is the kind of button displayed to the left of the cell when in editing mode.
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // No editing style if not editing or the index path is nil.
    if (self.editing == NO || !indexPath)
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`shouldIndentWhileEditing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/shouldIndentWhileEditing)!

Comment: Brilliant. Sometimes apple is so obvious, sometimes so cryptic. In this case, obvious, if you know where to look. Thank you. The exclamation point also helped. ;)